# Where do gems install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to edit one of the gem's config files and I can't find it. I'm not sure how I did this in the past.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Look at your gem environment.

In a terminal run `gem env`

You should see an entry `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`, but there is also `GEM PATHS` which is where it's loading all your gems from in your current environment.

Comment: Note that by console he means terminal or cmd. Not the rails console.

Answer (score 62):

**Rvm**

```
$ rvm gemdir
```

Or you can check:

```
echo $GEM_HOME
```

**Bundler**

```
$ bundle show --paths
```

For specific gem:

```
$ bundle show 'gem_name'
```

**Gem**

```
$ gem env
```

For specific gem:

```
$ gem which 'gem_name'
```

Answer (score 18):

To see the default installation directory, run

`gem env gemdir`

If you want to change the default installation directory (for example, to ~/.gem/ruby/2.1.0), add this line to ~/.bashrc

`export GEM_HOME=~/.gem/ruby/2.1.0`

And you also need to make sure ~/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin is in your PATH environment variable to use the commands provided by gem packages. If not, add this line to ~/.bashrc

`export PATH=$PATH:~/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin`

Answer (score 3):

If you are editing the gem's installed files, then the gem wasn't implemented correctly, or you are not modifying it correctly.

Proper gems are usually configured:

- via an initializer script on `config/initializers`
- via monkeypatching on `lib`
- via generators provided by the gem itself. These tend to generate lots of files, but they usually have a "initialize" or "install" option for setting up the gem.