# Ruby On Rails - Where to gems actually go

Tags: rubygems

When I do sudo gem install XYZ where does that code actually go? Are gems written in ruby on another language?

When I do bundle install, what does that do? I read through the rails tutorial, but it seemed to leave out those important details.

Comment: Ruby gems are Ruby gems - not specifically Ruby on Rails!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do gems install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408868/where-do-gems-install)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in your console use command:

```
gem env
```

There will be INSTALLATION DIRECTORY

Answer (score 3):

The command

```
bundle install
```

installs the gems listed in your Gemfile.  If you are installing gems using bundle, you can type

```
bundle show <gem name>
```

to see the directory that it is installed in.  If I were you I'd navigate to one of those directories and view the code -- it's usually ruby code (but can sometimes involve C).  (Look in the 'lib' subdir first -- that's where most of the code usually is).