# Ruby on Rails - Normalize-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed normalise-rails gem in my project and it all seems to work fine.
But I notice there is no css file generated in the app and I'm curious to know how this is working.
This is not a problem and such but it will be good to know what has happened in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Look, to make it work you added to application.css [these lines](https://github.com/markmcconachie/normalize-rails#usage):

```
*= require_self
*= require normalize-rails
*= require_tree .
```

And middle line just requires `normalize-rails.scss` file that you can found in gem's [vendor/assets/stylesheets](https://github.com/markmcconachie/normalize-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets) directory.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the gem isn't downloaded in your project. All the gems are installed in your `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` - [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408868/where-do-gems-install).

If you want to use an edited version of [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/), then just download the [stylesheet](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css) and save it in your app's

```
vendor/assets/stylesheets/
```

folder and include that file in your

```
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```

, like:

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require normalize
 *= require_self
*/
```